# Serializing an image as android

Tags: java, android

Good friends of the forum, Please have a look at my question.

What happens, I take several days esque looking to serialize an image in android and get results in a String with the serialization code.
I have searched far and the only thing I have found are methods to convert other objects to physical objects on the hard drive ...

Please if anyone knows how to do this procedure, I would appreciate a lot :)

salu2

Comment: It is not really clear what you mean. If you want to encode the image to a printable string, have a look at Base64 encoding.

Comment: Is similar, but I would like not to use external libraries or additional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested it but this should work (I could be wrong, no time to test sorry!!!)

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object   
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();  
String result = new String(b);
```

Comment: Converting a byte array with binary data to a String is very bad style and will cause sooner or later trouble. For saving binary data in a String encode it with base64 or similar.

Comment: I know, but from what I understand from this question, this is what he wants... He will probably make a post about "OutOfMemoryExceptions" in a few days, but it still was his question (if I understand it right).

Comment: Hmm, Both answers are debatable, but I would like not to use additional libraries.

Comment: Could you explain us a bit more what you really want to do?

Comment: If a simple encoding is needed, have a look at Hexadecimal encoding

Comment: I need is to convert the image to send text within a tag in an XML file